# What cell voltage should I use to charge a 2S 7.4 V LiPo battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, batteries

My battery charger asks for a cell voltage. To charge to full, should this be set to 7.4 V or is the 7.4 V split between the two cells? If you know of any good resourses to look at on batteries that would be excellent.

[image: Battery Changer]

Here is the battery I want to charge.

[image: Battery]

Comment: Welcome to our community! Also in case you didn't know, there's a li-po tag in the new [Drones.SE](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this setting is OK.

**One** LiPo cell will have a (maximum) voltage of around 4.2 V.

2S means that there are **2 cells in series**. In series means that the voltages add up so for a 2S battery you get 4.2 V + 4.2 V = 8.4 V.

Now things get confusing because on your battery is says **7.4 V**!

When a LiPo cell is fully charged its voltage is around 4.2 V

When a LiPo cell is almost empty its voltage is around 3.7 V

What they list on batteries is the "almost empty" voltage which is around 3.7 V per cell, of which there are 2 in series so: 3.7 V + 3.7 V = 7.4 V.

Your charger also says "2S (7.4 V)" so that's OK.

The **Current setting** might be a bit high. I would take that down to 2 or 3 A especially if you can accept the longer charging time.

Charging / discharging cells with high currents decreases their lifetime so if you can, take it slow, use a lower current.

Start learning at [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/)

Comment: I have seen conflicting information on the Amps most seem at suggest 1/1000 of the mAh but like you say 5A does seem high. Source - https://rogershobbycenter.com/lipoguide#:~:text=Most%20LiPo%20batteries%20need%20to,no%20more%20than%20three%20amps.